# How to check if child occurs multiple times in a dictionary

Tags: ios, swift, dictionary

I am querying some data and saving it to a dictionary in Swift like this:

```
[[route1: [date, destination, description], 
[route2: [date, destination, description]]]
```

I want to check whether the 'destination' occurs multiple times, and then save those entries to a separate dictionary. I can do the first part of checking, but I cannot figure out how I can then save each reccuring element of [route: [date, destination, description]] to a separate dictionary. The only way I can do it, is by adding them when there is more than one, but then I miss the first one. 
Can someone tell me how to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a new dictionary (let's call it `reverseMap`).

Loop over each key-value pair in your original dictionary.

For each pair:

In your `reverseMap`, see if you have a *key* yet containing your original dictionary's *value* (standardized if necessary to collapse similar values you want to consider necessary, e.g., arrays in different orders, or if you only care about `destination` being the same). If you don’t have one yet, create it, setting the value to an array with one element: the current *key* from your original dictionary.

If you *do* already have such a key, you have found a duplicate; at this point, you should *add to the array* at `reverseMap[key]` containing the current key from your original dictionary.

This should provide all the information you need. When you are done, `reverseMap` will contain, for each `value` in your original dictionary, a complete list of every key in your original dictionary that mapped to that value.